# Switch to another tab in tabhost with intent

Tags: android

I have 3 tab in tab host, I want switch to another tab with intent by click button..

```
TabSpec Tab1 = tabhost.newTabSpec("Tab1");
    jadwalUser.setIndicator("Tab1", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.style1));
    Intent in1 = new Intent(this, Tab1.class);
    Tab1.setContent(in1);

    TabSpec Tab2 = tabhost.newTabSpec("Tab2");
    Tab2.setIndicator("Tab2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.style2));
    Intent in2 = new Intent(this, Tab2.class);
    Tab2.setContent(in2);

    TabSpec Tab3 = tabhost.newTabSpec("Tab3");
    Tab3.setIndicator("Tab3", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.style3));
    Intent in3 = new Intent(this, Tab3.class);
    Tab3.setContent(in3);

    tabhost.addTab(Tab1);
    tabhost.addTab(Tab2);
    tabhost.addTab(Tab3);
```

I'm currently in Tab1, when this button clicked, i want to switch to Tab2 :

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
//What code here to switch to Tab2

}
}
```

Please help me, thanks..

Comment: You want to switch tabs with a button rather than actually using the tabs?  Why have tabs at all then?

Answer (score 0):

whats wrong with just calling

setCurrentTab of TabHost class

If you want to do it via intents one way could be

```
 Make your TabHost Activity single instance.

 override its onNewIntent delegate

 pass the id of the tab to open in the data of intent

 in onNewIntent call setCurrentTab method
```

You can also define broadcast listeners and send broadcast to switch betweeen tabs

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to reload your activity and set `setCurrentItem(position)` to your favorite tab index. (indexes starts with zero)